# Laravel Escape 'T' in Date Format Validation

Tags: html, laravel, validation

In a form I'm creating, I'm using the `datetime-locale` input. Taking today's date as example, the input field returns the date format as **2020-07-21T17:20**.

I'm trying to use Laravel's `date_format` validation to validate the input field's date. How do I escape the 'T' in the datetime of the return value of the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below validate:

```
$request->validate([
    'field' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i"'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `validationData` method if you are using a `FormRequest` and parse the date using Carbon. Or just simply do a `str_replace` ;)

```php
// form request
class MyFormRequest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest
{
    public function validationData()
    {
        $data = parent::validationData();

        $data['field'] = Carbon::parse($data['field'])->format('Y-m-d H:i');

        return $data;
    }
}

// controller
class MyController
{
    public function store(MyFormRequest $request)
    {
        // be aware that this doesn't return the formatted date value
        $request->post('field');

        // you could use this
        $request->validationData()['field'];
    }
}
```